# Why does Ruby Integer method 'chr' use ASCII-8bit, not UTF-8 by default?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

According to it's source code https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Integer:chr, this method uses ASCII encoding if no arguments provided, and really, it gives different results when called with and without arguments:

```
irb(main):002:0* 255.chr
=> "\xFF"

irb(main):003:0' 255.chr 'utf-8'
=> "ÿ"
```

Why does this happen? Isn't Ruby supposed to use UTF-8 everywhere by default? At least all strings seem to be encoded with UTF-8:

```
irb(main):005:0> "".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen?

For characters from U+0000 to U+007F (127), the vast majority of single-octet and variable-length character encodings agree on the encoding. In particular, they all agree on being strict supersets of ASCII.

In other words: for characters up to and including U+007F, ASCII, the entire ISO8859 family, the entire DOS codepage family, the entire Windows family, as well as UTF-8 are actually *identical*. So, for characters between U+0000 and U+007F, ASCII is the logical choice:

```ruby
0.chr.encoding
#=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>

127.chr.encoding
#=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

However, for anything *above* 127, more or less no two character encodings agree. In fact, the *overwhelming majority* of characters above 127 *don't even exist* in the overwhelming majority of characters sets, thus *don't have an encoding* in the vast majority of character encodings.

In other words: it is practically impossible to find a *single* default encoding for characters above 127.

Therefore, the encoding that is chosen by Ruby is `Encoding::BINARY`, which is basically a pseudo-encoding that means "this isn't actually text, this is unstructured unknown binary data". (For hysterical raisins, this encoding is also aliased to `ASCII-8BIT`, which I find absolutely horrible, because ASCII is 7 bit, period, and anything using the 8th bit is *by definition* not ASCII.)

```ruby
128.chr.encoding
#=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

255.chr.encoding
#=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Note also that [`Integer#chr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-chr) is limited to a single octet, i.e. to a range from 0 to 255, so multi-octet or variable-length encodings are not really required here.

> Isn't Ruby supposed to use UTF-8 everywhere by default?

Which encoding are you talking about? Ruby has about a half dozen of them.

For the vast majority of encodings, your statement is incorrect.

- the *locale encoding* is the default encoding of the environment
- the *filesystem encoding* is the encoding that is used for file paths: the value is determined by the file system
- the *external encoding* of an `IO` object is the encoding that text that this *read* is assumed to be in and text that is *written* is transcoded to: the default is the locale encoding
- the *internal encoding* of an `IO` object is the encoding that `String`s that are *written* to the `IO` object must be in and that `String`s that are *read* from the `IO` object are transcoded into: the default is the default internal encoding, whose default value, in turn, is `nil`, meaning no transcoding occurs
- the *script encoding* is the encoding that a Ruby script is read, and also `String` literals in the script will inherit this encoding: it is set with a magic comment at the beginning of the script, and the default is UTF-8

So, as you can see, there are many different encodings, and many different defaults, and only *one* of them is UTF-8. And *none* of those encodings are actually relevant to your question, because `128.chr` is neither a `String` literal nor an `IO` object. It is a `String` object that is created by the `Integer#chr` method using whatever encoding it sees fit.

Comment: _Note also that Integer#chr is limited to a single octet, i.e. to a range from 0 to 255, so multi-octet or variable-length encodings are not really required here._ In fact, chr method can work with multi byte characters, but only if you specify proper encoding, for example: `irb(main):002:0> 1050.chr 'utf-8' => "К"`

Comment: Your mention of "hysterical raisins" reminded me of some [famous TV ads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UShiwymsX0w) from the mid-1980's. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯